# orgmode - avoid duplicate tags in agenda view (inheritance)

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Is there a way to avoid having tags of headlines show up twice in the agenda view, If they are inherited, as well as set for a specific headline?

e.g.:

```
* heading 1                :tag1:
** TODO heading 2          :tag1:
```

shows up in my agenda as:

```
TODO heading 2       :tag1::tag1:
```

I am specifically looking for a solution, which doesn't remove inheritance of tags from `heading 1` , or from `:tag1:` itself, because I'd like for the inheritance to work for subheadings which do not carry the tag on their own.

Thanks for the help!